# How can I make php parse php.ini strictly?

Tags: php

The php command doesn't seem to check whether values in php.ini make sense. Here is an example:

```
$ echo 'memory_limit = foobar' > /tmp/php.ini
$ php -c /tmp -r 'printf("%s\n", ini_get("memory_limit"));'
foobar
```

How can I ask php to fail loudly when php.ini contains junk like this?

Comment: So to clarify, you are looking to validate whether an `ini` file contains legitimate data before parsing with `php`, correct?

Comment: Nope, that's not really what I'm asking for. I want to either set a flag on php or use some kind of "use strict" at the top of the php.ini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't.

- Ini-options are predefined with types (sort of).
- Thus they're not checked by the ini parser.
- Only the modules registering ini options ever actually interpret or complain about them. (They rarely do.)

In the case of memory_limit, it's predefined as

```
PHP_INI_ENTRY("memory_limit", "128M", PHP_INI_ALL, OnChangeMemoryLimit)
```

- Which means it's just a string.
- And it's interpretation is left up to the standard string to long parser `zend_atol`
- Somewhat of a core and reused function, thus does not interact with the error log
- And it just cares about numbers and some optional quantifier suffix `G` or `M` e.g.
- Anything else (garbage string) is interpreted as zero.

And for the purposes of `memory_limit` any 0 value is discarded. Because, you know, that wouldn't make sense for maximum memory usage.

Also PHP here simply assumes that at least one of all the possible `php.ini`s contains some sort of valid or sane default. So that's why (*I* would say) there's no loud warning for this. It's just not commonly needed. Which again - my opinion - is somewhat of a valid design choice: don't overoptimize for edge cases.